# setColorFilter not working

Tags: android, imageview, colorfilter

I'm trying to implement a simple colorfilter on an imageview to turn the black image into a white image. In order to achieve that I do the following:

```
    weatherImg.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    weatherImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.b_clouded_rain);
```

I've also tried to change to color in the color filter to red and white but all of them have no effect, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

As much as I hate to answer my own questions I found the problem:
I should've used:

```
   weatherImg.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP` it's the one used by default, `weatherImg.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE)` will work too ;)

Answer (score 30):

It depends on what kind of filtering you want to apply. If yout want to apply a new color on an image with transparencies on it, that's what worked for me:

```
weatherImg.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

If you want to learn more about this PorterDuff filters, I found a goog article that helped me understand: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-mer0918/ give it a read :)

Answer (score 21):

Had the same issue on Android 6. Solved by using `ImageView.getDrawable().setColorFilter()` instead of `ImageView.setColorFilter()`.

Comment: Not ideal for adapter items because if you are constantly modifying the backend list, you'll have to create new `ColorFilter` objects each time.

Comment: @TheRealChx101 What's the correct way to setColor for drawables in adapterItems?

Answer (score 6):

We use this code

```
Drawable drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(getDrawable(drawableResource));
        drawable.mutate();
        DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, getColor(color));
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

public static int getColor(int id) {
        return ContextCompat.getColor(getInstance().context, id);
    }

public static Drawable getDrawable(int id) {
        return ContextCompat.getDrawable(getInstance().context, id);
    }
```

Comment: exactly what I needed

Answer (score 6):

For me, simply calling `setColorFilter()` on the `ImageView` wasn't working.

```
imageView.setColorFilter(ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, color, null)) //didnt work on 21, only 22+
```

For whatever reason, on API 21, the only way I could get `setColorFilter()` to work properly was to post the change to the views message queue.

```
imageView.post { imageView.setColorFilter(ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, color, null)) } //this works on 21+
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having issues with `setColorFilter` on a Samsung S3 running 4.3 and the only way I could get the filter to work was by applying it in the `draw(Canvas canvas)` method:

```
public class ColouredDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {

private ColorFilter mColorFilter;

public ColouredDrawable(Bitmap toTransform, int toColour, Resources resources) {
    super(resources, toTransform);
    float[] matrix = {
            0, 0, 0, 0, ((toColour & 0xFF0000) / 0xFFFF),
            0, 0, 0, 0, ((toColour & 0xFF00) / 0xFF),
            0, 0, 0, 0, (toColour & 0xFF),
            0, 0, 0, 1, 0 };
    mColorFilter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    setColorFilter(mColorFilter);
    super.draw(canvas);
}
```

Simple applying `setColorFilter` to the BitmapDrawable didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Same problem on S4 4.4.4.

Comment: Same here with 2 samsung devices on 4.3 and 4.4.4! This is really bad!

Comment: Same here on Android before Lollipop. NinePatchDrawable is affected too. I solved by overriding the drawable class and setting the colorFilter to the paint object in the draw method:
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
  getPaint().setColorFilter(your_colorFilter);
  super.draw(canvas);
}

Comment: I ran into the 4.3 and 4.4 issue as well.  The correct answer is to use DrawableCompat.  See my solution below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48815950/5652513.

Answer (score 3):

I run into the same issue when using multiply

```
weatherImg.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

This worked for png icons but not for vector graphics.
Changing it to the default works for both:

```
 weatherImg.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Answer (score 2):

For me only this solution worked:

```
image.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
```

filter applies if `R.drawable.img` is vector image, and has no effect for raster resource

Answer (score 1):

I might have not the exact problem as yours and yet I think they similar when I try to change a color that not part of the predefined color such as YELLOW>BLUE>GRAY and just a few others, in ColorFiler I was getting the same result no matter what color I tried to use.

So when I used ....

```
imageView3.setColorFilter(0x85ffdd , PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

I was getting the same black color
Then I found

```
int color = Color.parseColor("#85ffdd");
```

now I have no problem to use any colors for my needs.

```
imageView3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int color = Color.parseColor("#85ffdd");
                imageView3.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                //get other images to default
                imageView1.clearColorFilter();
                imageView2.clearColorFilter();
            }
        });
```

I hope it might help you or others.

Answer (score 0):

For Android 4.3 and 4.4, setColorFilter does not work.  Use DrawableCompat instead.

```
    val drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(ContextCompat.getDrawable(
            context,
            R.drawable.b_clouded_rain));
    DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, foregroundColor);
    DrawableCompat.setTintMode(drawable, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
            .setColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

    weatherImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.b_clouded_rain);
```