# Random color not works and shows only one

Tags: java, android, random, arraylist, colors

I created an array with some colors and then i would that on click in my view the color of the view change in random order. this is what i have done so far

```
List<String> colors = new ArrayList<>();
   colors.add("#e84e40"); //red
   colors.add("#ec407a"); //pink
   colors.add("#ab47bc"); //purple
   colors.add("#7e57c2"); //deep purple
   colors.add("#5c6bc0"); //indigo
   colors.add("#738ffe"); //blue
   colors.add("#29b6f6"); //light blue
   colors.add("#26c6da"); //cyano
   colors.add("#26a69a"); //teal
   colors.add("#2baf2b"); //green
   colors.add("#9ccc65"); //light green
   colors.add("#d4e157"); //lime
   colors.add("#ffee58"); //yellow
   colors.add("#ffca28"); //amber


Random n= new Random(0);
color = n.nextInt(colors.size());
db.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(colors.get(color)), Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

But not works and instead shows all colors in random it shows only the green color always. Any idea?

EDIT:
if i write
`Random n= new Random();` it shows 2 colors.. something wrong with index maybe?

Comment: if you want truely random colors then make a new color
new Color(random.nextint(255),random.nextint(255),random.nextint(255));

Comment: But i want show that colors! i created the array for that reason..

Comment: I think the problem is here : `Mode.MULTIPLY` if i change the mode it change the colors.. always 2 anyway

Comment: it is definitely the PorterDuff mode. Multiply takes the source color and multiply it for the destination color

Comment: So how could i solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using LightingColorFilter,

```
Random n= new Random(0);
color = n.nextInt(colors.size());
db.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(color, 0));
```

Comment: always two colors.. differents but always two.

Comment: I think the problem is here : `Mode.MULTIPLY` if i change the mode it change the colors.. always 2 anyway

Comment: Yes that is what I am suspecting as well. Have a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18954101/713778

Comment: do you think using `SRC_ATOP` as Mode could i solve? now i try