# Xamarin, Android: Why is my imageview not changing its color?

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a drawable that is grey. Whenever the user likes a picture, this drawable however shall be in the color black (alphas of drawable need to stay).

I am doing this:

```
            ImgUpvote.SetColorFilter(Color.Red, PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
```

But it simply doesnt do anything.
I read something about mutating but that was Java and I couldnt find a translation for that.

Please help :)

This question is different because:

1) This here is c# NOT java
2) I am doing exactly as said on the other thread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setColorFilter not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954042/setcolorfilter-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do that:

```
            ImgUpvote.Background.Mutate().SetColorFilter(new Color(Color.Red), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);
```